# Getting error while adding a conditional check in .map() using ES6 syntax

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback, ecmascript-6

I need to assign only the object which contains iban value to the list in the below code.I couldn't fix this issue. kindly help.

```
  this.ibanList = this.data.map(
        (value, index)=> (if(value && value.iban){'id': index, 'text': value.iban}));
```

The values present inside the data is shown below.

```
 "data": [
        {

            "id": "2c4cc5e8-d24d-11e4-8833-150bbf360367"
        },
        {
            "iban": "DE45765459080",
            "id": "2c4cc8ae-d24d-11e4-8833-150bbf360367"
        },
        {

            "iban": "DE3700333333",
            "id": "8a23995d-10d7-11e5-b819-2c44fd83fb24"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: That's somewhat confusing, are you trying to **filter** out any object that doesn't have a `iban` key ?

Comment: ya.I need to verify it inside the callback using es6 syntax only

Comment: You can't filter with `map`, you have to return something ?

Comment: I need to return all the object containing id and iban in to the this.ibanList.

Comment: @user1645290: *"I need to return all the object containing id and iban in to the this.ibanList."* That's not what your code does. An entry *without* an `id` that does have an `iban` will be included on the list, and you're replacing `id` with the index. Did you really mean to do that? Those `id` values look...important.

Comment: "An entry without an id that does have an iban will be included on the list, and you're replacing id with the index."  thats correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two problems:

1. The shorthand form of an arrow function must have only an *expression* on the right-hand side of the `=>`. You have an `if` statement instead. (In parentheses, which wouldn't be valid anywhere, even outside an arrow function.)
2. `map` always uses the return value. You haven't given any return value for the "else" case.

In this specific case, you can use the conditional operator instead; I'll use `null` as the return value for the "else" case:

```
this.ibanList = this.data.map(
    (value, index)=> (value && value.iban ? {'id': index, 'text': value.iban} : null));
```

```js
var data = [
  {"id": "2c4cc5e8-d24d-11e4-8833-150bbf360367"},
  {"iban": "DE45765459080", "id": "2c4cc8ae-d24d-11e4-8833-150bbf360367"},
  {"iban": "DE3700333333", "id": "8a23995d-10d7-11e5-b819-2c44fd83fb24"}
];
var ibanList = data.map(
    (value, index)=> (value && value.iban ? {'id': index, 'text': value.iban} : null));
console.log(ibanList);
```

Note, though, that the result will have those `null`s in it. If you **only** want ones where `value && value.iban` is true, use `filter` before mapping:

```
this.ibanList = this.data
    .filter(value => value && value.iban)
    .map((value, index) => ({'id': index, 'text': value.iban}));
```

```js
var data = [
  {"id": "2c4cc5e8-d24d-11e4-8833-150bbf360367"},
  {"iban": "DE45765459080", "id": "2c4cc8ae-d24d-11e4-8833-150bbf360367"},
  {"iban": "DE3700333333", "id": "8a23995d-10d7-11e5-b819-2c44fd83fb24"}
];
var ibanList = data
    .filter(value => value && value.iban)
    .map((value, index) => ({'id': index, 'text': value.iban}));
console.log(ibanList);
```

In that case, I've used `filter` **before** mapping, which means that the `index` value you're using as `id` may well be different from the original. If you wanted the original value, pre-filtering, you'd filter afterward by combining the two approaches above:

```
this.ibanList = this.data
    .map((value, index)=> (value && value.iban ? {'id': index, 'text': value.iban} : null))
    .filter(value => value); // Removes the nulls
```

```js
var data = [
  {"id": "2c4cc5e8-d24d-11e4-8833-150bbf360367"},
  {"iban": "DE45765459080", "id": "2c4cc8ae-d24d-11e4-8833-150bbf360367"},
  {"iban": "DE3700333333", "id": "8a23995d-10d7-11e5-b819-2c44fd83fb24"}
];
var ibanList = data
    .map((value, index)=> (value && value.iban ? {'id': index, 'text': value.iban} : null))
    .filter(value => value); // Removes the nulls
console.log(ibanList);
```

---

Did you *really* mean to replace the `id` values (`"2c4cc5e8-d24d-11e4-8833-150bbf360367"` and such) with indexes? If not, replace `id: index` in the above with `id: value.id`.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```js
    
var data = [{id:1, text: "1", iban: 'foo'}, {id:2, text: "2", iban: 'bar'}, {id:10, text: 20}];
var ibanList = data.filter((value) => value && value.iban).map(
        (value, index) => ({'id': index, 'text': value.iban}));
console.log(ibanList);
```

Answer (score 1):

For `map` you need to always return a value, so to get the desired result you would need to `filter` your list first.

```
this.ibanList = this.data.filter(value => value && value.iban)
     .map((value, index) => ({id: index, text: value.iban}));
```

Comment: I think that you need to wrap the {} inside parenthesis because it will be interpreted as block with labels not object.

Comment: You are absolutely right, not sure where my head was when I wrote this! Thanks

Comment: Really easy to confuse `filter` and `reduce` :-)

Answer (score 0):

No need for map filter combo. This can be done with a single reduce in O(n) time.

```js
var data = [{"id": "2c4cc5e8-d24d-11e4-8833-150bbf360367"},{"iban": "DE45765459080","id": "2c4cc8ae-d24d-11e4-8833-150bbf360367"},{"iban": "DE3700333333","id": "8a23995d-10d7-11e5-b819-2c44fd83fb24"}],
ibanList = data.reduce((p,c,i) =>  (c.iban && p.push({"id": i, "text": c.iban}),p),[]);
console.log(ibanList)
```

Comment: I just threw up in my mouth a little at the comma operator, not to mention the `&&` with side-effects. :-) Seriously, we just do not need code to be that easily misread/misunderstood/hard to debug. Using `reduce` is a reasonable option without those, though.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder It's a matter of getting used to the style. Well... for me it's perfectly fine and easy to debug. I almost never use `if` and god forbid `else`... Besides...this is the most efficient piece of code within the whole answers here. How about that..?

Comment: No, it's not a matter of getting used to it. I'm very used to the comma operator and `&&` side-effects. I just don't use them, having seen too much time wasted on bugs resulting from them. If you like it, use it. Yes, all of the other answers make two passes. 99.99999% of the time, it makes exactly **zero** difference in real-world terms. You have to be dealing with millions upon millions of entries for it to matter. Now, of course, it's entirely possible to do a single pass via `reduce` with nice clear code. (Warning: Subjective terms used. ;-) )

Answer (score -1):

Use filter instead of map.

```
this.ibanList = this.data.filter((value, index) => {return value && value.iban});
```